# Psalm multiline associative array annotation

Tags: php, arrays, phpstorm, psalm-php

I'm using Psalm style annotations to document for instance return array types, such:

```php
/**
  * @return array{ key1: type1, key2: type2, key3: array{ nestedKey1: array<string,string> } }
  */
```

This works like a charm for autocomplete / static analysis, including PhpStorm. However, these lines can get just absurly long and impossible to follow, especially where nested arrays are involved.

I'm looking for a multiline syntax for this annotation, where I can have something like:

```php
/**
  * @return array{ 
  *    key1: type1, 
  *    key2: type2, 
  *    key3: array{ 
  *      nestedKey1: array<string,string> 
  *    } 
  *  }
  */
```

However as it's written this doesn't appear to be valid parsed syntax. Is there some syntax that would allow me to break the definition on multiple lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no, there isn't. Here's a request for this on the PhpStorm tracker:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-59784

Answer (score 3):

Seems to be totally supported by Psalm: https://psalm.dev/r/2feeaae2fb

It's often easier to split out individual parts into their own type aliases though, e.g.: https://psalm.dev/r/733049a5f4

Comment: Well, I'm aiming for readability though; if some of the nested structures might represent entities in their own right, this might be an approach, even defining a global @template for them. But otherwise, it's just clutter...